# Is there any other way then document.write?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a control panel, people can write a news article and it will print itself in a `.js` file like so:

```
document.write("<h1>title</h1><p>content</p>");
```

They can place the news article on their site like so:

```
<script src="http://example.com/news.js"></script>
```

But I think that's a very cheap way do to that. Does anyone have an better idea to do this without it being cheap? The `news.js` must stay on my server.

Comment: Why is it cheap? This is what `document.write` was designed to do.

Comment: what do you mean with cheap?

Comment: @Juhana People can disable javascript and the whole news article disappears. Is there any other way? Maybe PHP based?

Comment: Obviously there is no way to do it with JavaScript and make it work for people who have JavaScript disabled. You can do it with PHP or any other server-side language but then the inclusion must be done on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by being "cheap"?

Any how, you should be able to also use `document.body.appendChild` to append let's say, a node.

```
var node = document.createElement("h1");
document.body.appendChild(node);
```

Bare in mind that `document.write` is also "okay" for injecting some string into the document and can be useful in many ways.

Also worth mentioning that if the browser has disabled Javascript, your code won't work :-)

Comment: Interesting, can you give me some more information on this? And why did you chose li in particular?

Comment: I wrote `li` as an example. Have a look at the documentation for appending a node to the DOM: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Comment: It's not a great example since you are appending it to the body element… where it isn't allowed.

Comment: @Quentin why are you saying that it is now allowed? Could you please post a reference.

Comment: [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) — li elements are only allowed as children of ul elements or ol elements.

Comment: @Quentin Oh my God. I could have named it `foo`, that was an example of demonstrating the `appendChild` function, I don't believe he even needed to add a `li` tag but a `h1` one. I'll update the answer so you're happy — and by the way, my example would work even with a `li` tag, as it is allowed even if not valid markup.

Comment: I never said it wouldn't work (browsers let you get away with all kinds of stupid things), I just said it wasn't a great example.

Comment: @Quentin fair enough :-)